# Reading Response Headers from Google Cloud Storege API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using following code for downloading images from google cloud storage. But I am not able to see the eTAG, expires on  headers in response. when I use the image url in browser I can see those tags. Is there a way I can read response headers when fetching data from google cloud storage?

```
// Creates a client.
client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
}

rc, err := client.Bucket("mybucket").Object(imageName).NewReader(ctx)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)

    return
}
defer rc.Close()
```

Comment: Hi @max it seems that getting the `etag` is not as simple as we would think with Cloud Storage. It seems that you will need to read the metadata and then, find the `etag` value there. Considering that, could you please give it a try reading the metada of your file - an example is available [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#code-samples) - and check if the `.Etag` is available? If not, please, give it a try following this code [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1511#issuecomment-513413610), where the `etag` is returned successfully.

Comment: Thanks @gso_gabriel , metadata has etag . I used the link suggested by you https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#code-samples. It is just that I have to make two calls, one for image and other for metadata. You can make it as answer to this question instead of comment. will mark it as right answer

Comment: Hi @max glad to hear it helped you! I have posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that getting the `etag` is not as simple as we would think with Cloud Storage. For you to be able to get the `etag`, you will need to load the metadata from the object first, so you can find the `etag` there. You can use this documentation [Viewing and editing object metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#code-samples), so you can get code samples on how to return the image and then, the metadata with the `etag`. Considering what you will need to do to reach the `etag`, bear in mind that you will need to make two calls to achieve it - one for the image and another for the metadata itself.